# Clearing cin input: is cin.ignore not a good way?

Tags: c++

What's a better way to clear `cin` input? I thought `cin.clear` and `cin.ignore` was a good way?

Code:

```
 void clearInput()
{   
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(1000,'\n');
    //cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n' );

}
```

My teacher gave me this reply:

> this is basically saying that your
>   clearInput doesn't work FYI:  ignore
>   is NEVER a good idea as a way of
>   getting rid of all that remains on a
>   line
>
> and your failing this test is exactly
>   the reason why now go clear it the
>   correct way

She has also told me this following:

> on ignore you need to guess at how
>   many characters you want to ignore If
>   you absolutely know your data and it
>   follows a strict format -- as in Excel
>   spreadsheets, ignore is really good. 
>   If you are NOT in this type of file,
>   then you NEVER use ignore.  Question,
>   is your data well-formed?  If yes, use
>   ignore.  If not, don't use ignore.
>
> List ALL the way of getting data? 1)
>   there is extraction >>
>
> and there is also??????
>
> please list for me

Comment: Why?  Does he think ignore means "ignore"?  It extracts and tosses the characters, presumably what he wanted you to do manually.

Comment: Sounds like your teacher is kind of mean. As far as I know, `clear` then `ignore` is the standard way to clear the line. Then again my stream knowledge is low.

Comment: I'd go a little further than "kind of mean." Best luck on the class and it sounds like maybe you should "ignore" him.

Comment: Yeah, the teacher is pretty short in her answers and definitely comes off more than mean.

What if I were to use 

string junk;
cin>>junk;

?

Comment: That would only read up to the first whitespace; to read the whole line you can use the global `getline` function (by the way, sorry for suggesting `ignore` in your other question, seeing as that seems to be the wrong answer!  Though I still don't see why ;))

Comment: i assume a global function requires a global variable, which we are not able to use..

as these functions i have are all individually tested,how do I go about testing them?

(aka, how do i check if the line's cleared?)

Comment: Using global `getline` doesn't require a global variable (you use it like:`string junk; getline(cin, junk);`).  The testing thing is a good point though: using `cin` (which is a global variable) makes it hard to test the functions in isolation... if you're allowed to you could make the functions take a `std::ostream&` argument and use that in place of `cin` - then you can easily test them by passing e.g. an `istringstream`.

Comment: You can use `std::cin.ignore(LLONG_MAX, '\n');`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your teacher’s reply are a bit unclear (at least to me).

Concerning `ignore`, your teacher is wrong in principle: `ignore` is [the standard idiom](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#istream-and-ignore) of how to clear a stream (as shown by Potatocorn, this is even mentioned in the standard).

However, it’s important to notice that `cin.ignore(1000)` is *indeed* a bad way of doing this: this just presumes that there won’t be more than 1000 characters in the buffer. Never use such a magic number in `ignore`.

Instead, either use

1. `cin.rdbuf()->in_avail()` (i.e. the available number of chars in the read buffer)<sup>1)</sup>, or use
2. `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()`.

---

<sup>1)</sup> Unfortunately, `in_avail` is broken on some recent VC (?) compilers so this method isn’t very portable.

Comment: right, i'm not exactly sure what she wants out of me here..

there is extraction (>>), i guess the other one she is thinking of is getline? could cin.getline and cin.clear be used in this regard?

and how do i know if the input has been cleared?

Comment: @igor: you could repeatedly `getline` (or `get`) until EOF or failure is signalled. But I don’t see how this would be in any way superior to `ignore`.

Comment: her reply to me asking why i cannot use ignore as Red-nosed unicorn pointed out:

http://pastebin.com/eTWkPuFb

Comment: “What will work in all cases?” – easy: either of the codes I posted above. These codes will work no matter how many characters the user has entered *because they’re defined that way*!

Comment: yes, that works of course. i still don't know what she wants haha.

Comment: `in_avail` shouldn't be used to determine a program's behavior; it just counts items left in the input buffer. It doesn't tell you about how much is left in the *stream*. The (preallocated) buffer space is exhausted quite regularly, and emptying the buffer does not necessarily cause it to refill from the beginning. Of course there is no way to tell how much input is left in an interactive stream, such as `cin` often is.

Comment: @Potatoswatter But that’s exactly what we want! We want to see how much is left in the buffer, and read all of these characters (via `ignore`), so that the *next* read operation (the one we actually want to perform), will wait for the next character (= next user input) to enter the buffer. I don’t understand to which step in that chain you object.

Comment: @KonradRudolph If the buffer has a capacity of 1000 chars, and the "get pointer" points to the 999'th, then `in_avail` can only return 1. You don't know anything about how much is actually left. You're attaching semantic significance to the state of something which is supposed to be transparent. Buffering does not change the behavior of a file.

Comment: You might be confusing the iostreams buffer with the line buffer maintained by the shell program — that's an entirely different process.

Answer (score 5):

Copy-pasting from the standard,

> ```
> basic_istream<charT,traits>&
> ignore(streamsize n = 1, int_type
> delim = traits::eof());
> ```
>
> *Effects:* Behaves as an unformatted
>   input function (as described in
>   27.6.1.3, paragraph 1). After constructing a sentry object,
>   extracts characters and discards them.
>   Characters are extracted until any of
>   the following occurs:
>
> - if `n != numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()`
>     (18.2.1), `n` characters are extracted
> - end-of-file occurs on the input sequence (in which case the function
>     calls `setstate(eofbit)`, which may
>     throw `ios_base::failure` (27.4.4.3));
> - `c == delim` for the next available input character `c` (in which case `c` is
>     extracted).

You commented line with `numeric_limits<>::max` is superior, but it looks like you didn't want to use something you didn't completely understand, which is also good.

The only thing someone could possibly want besides `ignore` is non-blocking behavior, i.e. don't wait for the user to press return if the terminal is in unbuffered mode. But that's just entirely unsupported by iostreams as far as I know.

Comment: TILT: "If n != numeric_limits::max() (18.2.1), n characters are extracted.". But, there's no mention of what happens when n == numeric_limits::max() !

Comment: @Casey It's unlimited. `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()` is seldom less than 4 GB, so you're out of luck if you need to ignore exactly 4 GB +  1.