# Do...While() loop does not work fine

Tags: c++, file, loops, do-while

I am prompting the user to enter data regarding  cars. The Do...while() loop I am using works fine the first time, then does not work properly after the first time. The code is bellow, and I am using Dev-C++. Thank you for your help and time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<cstring>
#include<fstream>
#include <iomanip.h>


using namespace std;

int main()
{

  char manufacturer[16], model[16], year[10], miles[10], car_cost[12];
  char response;
  ofstream OS ("usedcars.txt", ios::out);
  cout<<"for each car please enter :"<<endl;

  do
  {
    ofstream OS ("usedcars.txt", ios::app);
    cout<<"The manufacturer: ";
    cin.getline(manufacturer, 16);
    cout<<"The model: ";
    cin.getline(model, 16);
    cout<<"The year: ";
    cin.getline(year, 8);
    cout<<"The miles: ";
    cin.getline(miles, 8);
    cout<<"The cost of car $: ";
    cin.getline(car_cost, 10);

   OS << manufacturer << setw(9) << model << setw(8) << year << setw(11)<< miles << setw(8) << car_cost << endl;
  cout<<"Do you want to continue?";
  cin>>response;

 }
 while (response!='n');  


  return 0;  
}
```

************the outpu of the program*******************

```
for each car please enter :
The manufacturer: Toyota
The model: corolla
The year: 2005
The miles: 123,000
The cost of car $: 7,999
Do you want to continue?y
The manufacturer: The model: Honda
The year: Civic
The miles: 67,850
The cost of car $: 9,200
Do you want to continue?n
```

******usedcars.txt*****************************

```
Toyota  corolla    2005    123,000   7,999
    Honda   Civic     67,850   9,200
```

Comment: *does not work properly after first time* It hangs, It crashes, It flies off, It explodes? How are we supposed to know unless you specifically tell us?

Comment: No, I guess it "dies in flames" :)

Comment: I think the file usedcars.txt is empty or may be it is read error

Comment: You only need to open the file once – delete the first line of the do loop. What Azrael3000 said is the actual problem, but you should fix this too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose you press enter after entering the 'y' for response. But you only read in one character which is y. So the '\n' gets passed to the next read which is your Manufacturer. Thus there is no data there.

As stefaanv writes use cin.ignore. An interesting bit on this can be found here: [Clearing cin input: is cin.ignore not a good way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573435/clearing-cin-input-cin-ignore-not-a-good-way)

Comment: Solve this by adding a cin.ignore call before the first cin.getline

Comment: Lol, Sorry for not being clear enough, but you did guess the meaning of "does not work". I added cin.ignore just after I entered 'y' or 'n' and it works fine now!  Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. Just remember next time to format your question better and specify your problem as accurately as possible.

Comment: @stefaanv: Solve this by not mixing operator>> and getline() calls. Just make the read of a response a getline(). `

Answer (score 1):

the `do while` loop seems alright. Update your question with error or bugs that you encounter. 
the only problem i can think of from the code is that the stream isnt closed after iteration. you have to close the stream when user `response` is `n`

Comment: I missed a cin.ignore before the first getline(). it works fine now. I will close the stream as you mentioned. Thanks again!

Comment: oh okay!! Better question next time pls