# C++ Character Validation issue

Tags: c++, validation

This validation of a (Y/N) input in a console application works but if the user inputs nothing and simply presses the "Enter" button then the cursor will not return to its original two dimensional position. (it returns to the line below its original position)

I have no idea why. Here's the code:

```
char again(int col, int row)
{
char reply;

do
{
    gotoXY(col, row);
    cin >> noskipws >> reply;
    reply = toupper(reply);

    if ((reply != 'Y' && reply != 'N'))
    {
        message("Must Enter Y or N ", 5, row + 3);
        clearLine(col, row);            

    //  cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(150, '\n');
    }

    cin.setf(ios::skipws);      

} while (reply != 'Y' && reply != 'N'); 

return reply;
}
```

Any suggestions?

This should allow you to compile and view the issue:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h> 
#include <iomanip> 


using namespace std;

VOID gotoXY(short x, short y);
char again(int col, int row);
void clearLine(int col, int row);
void pressKey(int col, int row);
void message(char message[], int col, int row);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
char  reply; 
do
{
    gotoXY(5, 13);
    cout << "Do you want to run the program again (Y/N):";
    reply = again(51, 13);

    cin.ignore(150, '\n');

} while (reply == 'Y');

return 0;
}
VOID gotoXY(short x, short y)
{
COORD c = { x, y };
SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), c);
}


void message(char message[], int col, int row)
{
gotoXY(col, row);
cout << message;
pressKey(col, row + 2);
clearLine(col, row);
clearLine(col, row + 2);
}

void pressKey(int col, int row)
{
gotoXY(col, row);
cout << "Press any key to continue...";
_getch();
}


void clearLine(int col, int row)
{
//Used to clear prompts and user input
gotoXY(col, row);

for (int i = col; i <= 80; i++)
{
    cout << " ";
}
}

char again(int col, int row)
{
char reply;

do
{
    gotoXY(col, row);
    cin >> noskipws >> reply;
    reply = toupper(reply);

    if ((reply != 'Y' && reply != 'N'))
    {
        message("Must Enter Y or N ", 5, row + 3);
        clearLine(col, row);
        cin.setf(ios::skipws);
        //  cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(150, '\n');
    }

    /*cin.setf(ios::skipws);*/

} while (reply != 'Y' && reply != 'N');

return reply;
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more context.   What do `message()` and `clearLine()` do?  When you say the cursor does not return to its current position, do you mean horizontal position (e.g. to a particular offset from left margin) or two dimensional position (e.g. horizontal and vertical offset from top left hand side of screen)?   Lastly, what environment is your program running in - is it a console application, and are you relying on particular device characteristics (e.g. ability to move cursor to a specific location on a 2D screen) that are not available on all screens?

Comment: @SkottokS : It would be great if you provided minimum but complete enough to understand the code which would compile succesfully

Comment: Is gotoXY() a pre-defined function (probably from <conio.h>)? If so, specify your operating system, compiler and how you run your application (otherwise, please provide source code of gotoXY()). Most "modern" functions are called gotoxy(), so I have a feeling you use rather obsolete library which can have weird effects in modern OS.

Comment: Your edits give a little more information (albeit `gotoXY()` is non-standard) but outputting 81 characters to a terminal that is only 80 characters wide (quite a few older/basic physical terminals and a fair few modern logical terminals) will wrap, and scroll down, no matter how you position the cursor before doing that.    There is not generally a direct relationship between functions that position the cursor and `std::cout`, even if the two happen to be affecting the same output device/window.

Comment: Thanks everyone, got it sorted. Cheers

Comment: @SkottokS If you were able to resolve the issue you should answer your own question and accept the answer for the sake of anyone coming along behind you who has the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the trick: when you press [T],[Enter], two symbols are added to stream: 't','\n'. First is read on `std::cin >> reply`, second is read on `std::cin.ignore(150,'\n');`.

But when you press just [Enter], only '\n' is added to stream. It is read to reply, and when control reaches `std::cin.ignore(150,'\n');`, there are no symbols to read from the stream; at the moment, input cursor is left where `clearLine()` left it and all further input until '\n' (or first 150 symbols) will be ignored.

Simple (though not the best) solution would be to check `if (reply != '\n') cin.ignore(150, '\n');`. Better idea is to read not a character, but `std::string` from the start - this will remove necessity for ignore in your scenario. Also, see this question: [Clearing cin input: is cin.ignore not a good way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573435/clearing-cin-input-is-cin-ignore-not-a-good-way)